# How to find xpath expression to select this text

Tags: xpath

I have this html code , trying many times to get the pure xpath for text "sample text" then "author" text in separate xpath and i don't find any criteria for that!!!

```
<div class="Text">
      “sample article here with quotation marks .”   
<br/>
  ―     
<a href="/author/link/xxxxx/">Author</a>
```

so please help , it make me mad!!
thanks

Comment: Where does </div> come ?

Comment: @curiosu I'm assuming the closing `div` is coming just after the `a` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part you can get by getting the `div` by `class`, get `br` inside and retrieve the `preceding-sibling`'s text:

```
//div[@class="Text"]/br/preceding-sibling::text()
```

The second part is easier, just get the text of `a` tag inside the `div`:

```
//div[@class="Text"]/a/text()
```